# Supporting authentication with spring security and Linkedin login via spring social

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-3, spring-social

I have an application which suports login via linkedin and normal signin.For normal signin spring security is used and for linkedin signin spring social is using.If a user signup with linkedin password field in user table will be null.When that user tries to login through normal signin process an Http 500 error is occuring the exception details is as follows...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encoded password cannot be null or empty
    org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(BCryptPasswordEncoder.java:77)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider$1.isPasswordValid(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:148)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:149)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:59)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    au.com.kingcontent.platform.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

How to handle this error... and show an error message for the user?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running into [SEC-1890](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-1890). Please update to either 3.1.6.RELEASE or 3.2.2.RELEASE version of Spring Security and see if it fixes your issue.